# How to get swagger.io and swashbuckle to pass back api_key via Bearer token?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jwt, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've been following a number of sources to try and implement JWT authentication into my WebApi2 project and have also started using [swagger.io](http://swagger.io/) and [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to both document and test my API.  I've been inspired by how [exceptionless](https://collector.exceptionless.io/docs/index#!/Auth/Auth_Login) supports an `/auth/login` method to generate an `api_key` which is then used to call other methods requiring authorisation.

I should also say my development has been based on the [ASP.NET Web API 2](https://github.com/jamiekurtz/WebApi2Book) book which introduces Token-Based security using `JwtAuthForWebAPI` package and so I have my JWT Delegating Handler implemented for me as follows:

```
// Add Jwt Authentication Web Handler
var builder = new SecurityTokenBuilder();
var reader = new ConfigurationReader();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(
    new JwtAuthenticationMessageHandler
    {
        AllowedAudience = reader.AllowedAudience,
        Issuer = reader.Issuer,
        SigningToken = builder.CreateFromKey(reader.SymmetricKey),
        //SigningToken = builder.CreateFromKey(reader.SubjectCertificateName),
        CookieNameToCheckForToken = reader.CookieNameToCheckForToken
    });
```

(I've set up web.config credentials and the code steps through fine)

The problem is:

1. Unlike exceptionless, when I call a method after entering my `api_key`, swagger is putting the key onto the querystring instead of in a "Bearer" authorisation header
2. I don't know if the above code checks the querystring for the JWT (and even if it did, it doesn't sound that sensible for lots of reasons (security, long URL)
3. Because the above code builds the Delegating Handler for me, I can't debug it to see what it is actually doing (can I link [log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) into it?)
4. And as a result, my controller method doesn't get hit because `[Authorise]` fails.

My suppose my question at this point is to resolve item 1 above which will make 2 a non-issue and (hopefully) make 4 work!  Thanks.

Comment: My GET request mentione in item 1 looks like this: `http://localhost:57618/api/UserProfile?api_key=eyJ0eXAiOi...` and unsuprisingly returns a 401 status code.

Comment: OK, so I've found and implemented a solution (http://stevemichelotti.com/customize-authentication-header-in-swaggerui-using-swashbuckle/) for item 1 by Steve Michelotti (thanks Steve!) but as there is nowhere in the above code where you state the header "name" that contains the value, I still don't understand how the Delegated Handler can find my key.   (e.g. "apiKey" or "key" etc).  Is it because I should actually be setting "Authorization: Bearer ..." instead?

Comment: You can do it the way provided here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729188/im-not-getting-a-scope-checkbox-when-the-authorize-tag-doesnt-contain-roles-a/39750143#39750143

Comment: I work on the exceptionless project and implemented the oauth flow. I'm glad you got it working and was inspired by our project :). I really like how we are setup and I think it's dead simple.